# How to transpose out of order on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I'm working with a very large dataset and want to parse out useful information, but I cannot filter this information since some data points are so similar to others. Is it possible to transpose unique data points in Google Sheets

Say I have a list:

```
A
B
C
D
```

But I want to transpose only A, B, and D. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A; A2:A<>"C"; A2:A<>"")))
```

[image: 0]

---

to exclude multiple values try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A; NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A; "C|B|X")); A2:A<>"")))
```

note that regex is case sensitive